# Setting file extensions in ESLint configuration using overrides

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm trying to specify the file extensions that ESLint should check by setting `overrides` in the configuration rather than needing to use the `--ext` command line flag. The [documentation for that](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#-ext) says:

> By default, ESLint lints `*.js` files and the files that match the `overrides` entries of your configuration.

The [documentation for `overrides`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#how-do-overrides-work) says that glob patterns for `files` can be along the lines of  `"src/*.js"` or `"**/*.js"` and that these are relative to the base directory of your ESLint configuration file. Neither of these options are working for me to make ESLint process files beyond the default of `*.js` (in my case `*.jsx`).

Here's the output when I run ESLint with `--ext`:

```
scott@dev /home/scott/project (main)
$ npx eslint --ext .js,.jsx ./src

/home/scott/project/src/file.jsx
  1:1  warning  Unexpected console statement  no-console

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)
```

As expected, it produces a warning. But without `--ext`, ESLint doesn't produce any output.

The directory structure:

```
/home/scott/project/
  .eslintrc.js
  src/
      file.jsx
```

`.eslintrc.js`:

```js
const rules = {
    // ...
};

module.exports = {
    // ...
    overrides: [
        {
          files: [ "*.jsx" ], // also doesn't work with "src/**/*.jsx", "**/*.jsx"
          rules: rules
        }
    ],
    rules: rules
};
```

What do I have to do?

Comment: I just tried it out and it works fine for me.
Have you tried without the "rules" in the override. That works for me.
- actually not specifying the overrides and just giving defining what tsconfig.json to use (`parserOptions: { project: "your-tsconfig.json" }`), seemed to work as well

Comment: @Tokimon I'm no longer in the situation of needing an answer for this, but I'm also confused by your reference to `tsconfig.json` when TypeScript wasn't involved here.

Comment: Ah damn. Sorry yes I see that now. Sorry about the confusion then :-/

Comment: No harm no foul!